# External monitor options for MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

If I would like to attach a second monitor to my MacBook air is my only option the [Thunderbolt Display](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC914LL/B/apple-thunderbolt-display-27-inch)?  Everything I've found online points me there, but those are a cool grand, so I'm wondering if there are other options out there that I just don't know about.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean you want two external displays attached to the Air? If you just want one, you can use pretty much anything, given an adapter.

Comment: Just one for now.  So would I just need a Thunderbolt to "X" addapter?

Comment: In fact, you just need a mini-DisplayPort to "X" adapter, as Thunderbolt is backwards-compatible with mDP (per robmathers's answer).

Answer (score 2):

The Thunderbolt ports are also mini-Displayport compatible. So you can hook up pretty much any display (Displayport, HDMI, DVI, VGA) with the proper adapter.

For high-resolution panels (greater than 1920x1200), you should try to go with Displayport if possible, as the mini-Displaylink to dual-link DVI adapters have been problematic for many people (this isn't an issue for single-link DVI displays, which comprise all but the largest DVI displays around).